# Wholesale Price not shown on products page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with a page developed in WordPress and WooCommerce. Since I created my page I have been using the Wholesale Price plugin and it always worked fine until 2 days ago.
Currently, wholesale prices are not displayed on the product page or in the cart, but are displayed at checkout.

The information I can give is that I updated the database since the page itself asked me to do so. My version of WordPress is version 6.4.3.
Also, when I load my page and inspect it, I get a null value (reading 'addEventListener'). I guess that could be the problem too.
My intuition is a problem between connections but I don't know what it would be.
I already tried returning previous versions of the plugin and others too, even the theme I use but nothing worked.

Comment: With the provided details, nobody can guess by magic the reason of the issue you are facing. Always do a complete backup before any update action. You should always test update actions before on a staging website.